# Moving the focus from One EditText to Another (Horizontal Direction) - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a Scrollview as a parent view, within that i have placed some mixture of linear layout
and there is no probs in the design, but while testing the app, i found that there is a problem in movement of cursor, my intention is to move the focus from one edit text to another that is located adjecent(Horizontally), but when i click the enter button at the bottom, it moves the focus to the next edit text that is vertically located (I knoe,this is default one).

Even i tried with implementing the EditorAction, still the same issue exists.

This is the code that i used to move the focus from one edit text to another.

```
// Adding the special listener, to be invoked when the action is performed on the editor
    firstEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            // Move the focus to the next edittext(secondEditText)
                   secondEditText.requestFocus();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Please let me know, how to move the focus from one text box to another placed in a horizontal direction. The above code moves the focus to text box that is vertically located. I tried with searching google a lot, but no results.

I have also shared that screen for better clarity.

Hope i could get a better response here.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract void onFocusChange (View v, boolean hasFocus){
if(!hasFocus){
secondEditText.requestFocus();
}

}
```

but fails when scrolled up coz, even in that case the second EditText gets focus and not the above view..

a better solution could be,

```
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener lis = new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
                if(firstEditText.hasFocus){
                                     secondEditText.requestFocus();
                                      return true;
                                   }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                    float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        }
}
```